# More than three months on - parapharse that expresson for me, please

Tags: grammar

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/crimea-euphoria-fades-russians-104555489--business.html

> But **more than three months on**, she is worried that her wage of 9,000 roubles ($260) a month is not stretching as far as it used to, and fears she will be forced to take on extra work to cover the rising cost of food and utilities.

How would you paraphrase that expression? But don't use **on**, of course.

Comment: The simplest way to avoid using ***on*** there is to replace it with ***after [that]***, where *that* is simply a reference back to whatever time was introduced in earlier text that we don't have in the citation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase in question (and also *she*) reference the previous paragraph:

> Tatyana was caught up in the euphoria that gripped the nation when Russia annexed Crimea in March

*More than three months on* tells us that Tatyana has been experiencing this situation for more than three months; specifically, since the annexation in March. Here, the target of *on* has been ellipted, because it's understood.

You can catch the intent here by replacing *on* with *later* or *afterwards*. The general meaning is "since the state in question took effect":

> How's the work for that new client coming along?
>   After a month *on [the job]*, I think I'm getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use...

For the the last three months /
Three months since that /
Three months later

It does depend a little on what actually is before the word 'but'

Hope that helps